# Compiler Error on iterator using list<Object*> C++

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-keyword

I have been having some troubles with the following code.

```
#ifndef SGA_H
#define SGA_H

#include<list>
#include "BaseObject.h"
#include "TableSpace.h"

class SGA : public BaseObject {
private:
    list<TableSpace*> TB;
public:
    SGA();
    SGA(list<TableSpace*>);
    void save(ostream&) const;
    static SGA* read(ifstream&);
    string toString() const;
};

#endif  /* SGA_H */
```

Problematic code

```
void SGA::save(ostream& out) const{
    salida << "SGA" << endl;
    salida << TB.size() << endl;
    list<TableSpace*>::iterator it;
    for(it = TB.begin(); it != TB.end();it++){
        it->save(out);
    }
}
```

And this one too

```
string SGA::toString() const{
    stringstream cadena;

    cadena << "\nTable Spaces: ";
    list<TableSpace>::iterator i;
    for(i=TB.begin(); i != TB.end(); i++){
        cadena << (*i).toString();
    }
    return cadena.str();
}
```

What the compiler says is that there is no coincidence in `operator =`

Exactly the output is:

```
SGA.cpp:14:23: error: no coincidence 'operator=' en 'it = ((const SGA*)this)->SGA::TB.std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = TableSpace*, _Alloc = std::allocator<TableSpace*>, std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_List_const_iterator<TableSpace*>]()'
```

Comment: What compiler are you using and can you provide a minimal working example? The content of BaseObject.h and TableSpace.h might be relevant to the problem.

Comment: Try using list<TableSpace>::const_iterator instead of list<TableSpace>::iterator for the type of your iterator. Since you're implementing const methods, you cannot iterate over your list using a simple non-const iterator.

Comment: Have you solved your problem, or something is still wrong?

Comment: I have solved it by using the advices given to me here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you should try:

```
list<TableSpace*>::iterator it;
for(it = TB.begin(); it != TB.end();it++){
    (*it)->save(out);
```

Because after iteration you get a pointer to pointer.

---

Also, do you really need to declare all these methods `const`?? Are sure that it means?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `const_iterator` instead of `iterator`:

```
list<TableSpace*>::const_iterator it;
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know why that should make a difference, but now in the same code "it->save(out);" is underlined. Do you know why is this?

Comment: That has been answered by ST3 ;) The `const_iterator` has to be used, since you declared your method as `const`, so it isn't allowed to change the members of the class instance.

Answer (score 1):

you define the iterator as `list<TableSpace>::iterator i;` but try to iterate over a `list<TableSpace*> TB;` ... this might be an error.

Comment: Only in the second code section. The first code section iterates over `list<TableSpace*>`.

Comment: There's two errors, the compiler will show the second one once the first is fixed. Edit : 3 errors (cf ST3's answer)

Comment: @Callidior that is true also :) so here in the three answers we have found all the three bugs :)

Comment: Thank you so much guys. It was pretty fast your answers.

Answer (score 0):

As the functions in question are `const`, you should use `const_iterator`

For example:

```
class test{
    public:
    list<int> x;
    test(){
    }
    int get() const{
      list<int>::iterator i;
      for(i=x.begin();i!=x.end();i++)
        return *i;
    }
};

int main() {
    test a=test();
    a.x.push_back(10);
    cout<<a.get();
    return 0;
}
```

reproduces your error. While using `const_iterator` error is resolved.
http://ideone.com/e.js/zDyuQU

```
class test{
    public:
    list<int> x;
    test(){
    }
    int get() const{
      list<int>::const_iterator i;
      for(i=x.begin();i!=x.end();i++)
        return *i;
    }
};

int main() {
    test a=test();
    a.x.push_back(10);
    cout<<a.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I had forgotten about 'const' word. Thank you a lot.